# Attach a xls file to email and send -- via python

Tags: python

I have an xls file which has few images and graphs in it.
I would like to attach this file and send to an email.
Below is my code:

```
def create_message(report):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['From'] = msettings.EMAILS_SEND_FROM_NAME
    message['To'] = msettings.EMAILS_SEND_TO
    message['Subject'] = msettings.EMAILS_SUBJECT

    with open(report, "r") as file:
        payload = MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name=os.path.basename(report))
        content = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(report))
        payload['Content-Disposition'] = content
        message.attach(payload)
```

But I get the following Error

```
  message = create_message(file)
  line 148, in create_message
    payload = MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name=os.path.basename(report))
  File "python-3.4.3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 732: character maps to <undefined>
```

I doubt that the encoding of my xls file is not supported.
How can I attach a xls file with images,graphs and a lot of formatting as an attachment without losing any information from the xls file?

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you. I was able to solve the issue by referring to the link you provided.

Answer (score -1):

I have had good luck with the library `yagmail`, which would not only greatly simplify your code, but I've used attachments with no problem.

Comment: This is an anecdote, not an answer. This should probably be a comment on OP rather than as an answer, since it's not actually an answer.

Comment: It is a tool, that offers a solution, that is presented along with an anecdote -- it is certainly not a thorough answer, but it is not a comment. THIS, is a comment.